# Confusing Rspec-puppet deprecation warning: defaults mock_with to :mocha

Tags: puppet, rspec-puppet

When running Rspec-puppet tests, a deprecation warning is seen:

```
Deprecation Warnings:

puppetlabs_spec_helper: defaults `mock_with` to `:mocha`.
  See https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper#mock_with
  to choose a sensible value for you
```

Accordingly, I set up a spec_helper with a block like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.mock_with :mocha
  ...
end
```

Just like the documentation [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs_spec_helper#mock_with) suggests. But the warning persists. What is wrong?

Comment: It is worth clarifying here that what is deprecated is relying on a default mocking framework instead of specifying one explicitly.  The message helpfully adds that mocha is the default, but does not mention that the current recommendation is to use rspec-mocks (`:rspec`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually necessary to open two configuration blocks, whereas the `mock_with` config must be declared before the `puppetlabs_spec_helper` is required.

In other words, like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.mock_with :rspec
end

require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/module_spec_helper'

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.formatter = :documentation
  c.tty       = true
  ...
end
```

See also discussion in [here](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PDK-916).

I have asked and answered this question here so that this confusing behaviour is documented somewhere because no matter how clear the docs are, this is going to continue to trip people up.

Comment: ... or substitute `:rspec` in place of `:mocha` to switch to Rspec-mocks in conformance with the current recommendation (which may well require other changes).  The PDK team is trying to encourage folks to move away from Mocha, while avoiding breaking anything. Suppressing the warning by the mechanism shown here subverts that effort.  Myself, I'd recommend letting the warning persist until and unless one is prepared to switch to Rspec-mocks.

Comment: I changed it to :rspec. Note that I use https://github.com/Accuity/rspec-puppet-utils which is based on Mocha and AFAIK there's no Rspec-mocks equivalent.